# How to convert integer number and arrays of bytes to each other in C?

Tags: python, c, struct

After using Python, I found that its struct module can package numbers into byte strings or unpack byte strings into numbers.

the code is like this:

```py
import struct

struct.pack('>I', 13934)
# b'\x00\x006n'

struct.pack('>Q', 12345678901234567890)
# b'\xabT\xa9\x8c\xeb\x1f\n\xd2'

struct.unpack('>I', b'\x00\x006n')
# 13934

struct.unpack('>Q', b'\xabT\xa9\x8c\xeb\x1f\n\xd2')
# 12345678901234567890
```

How to implement such a function in C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you only need to understand the way data is stored in a computer.
Since all data in a computer is stored in binary format, it means that numbers and arrays are actually stored in the same way.

To achieve this function, it is necessary to understand how computers store numbers. Taking a program built using C code as an example, in a 64 bit computer, a `size_t` type number occupies 8 bytes, a `int` type number occupies 4 bytes, a `short` type number occupies 2 bytes.

like this:

```c
printf("%llu\n", sizeof(short));
printf("%llu\n", sizeof(int));
printf("%llu\n", sizeof(size_t));

// 2
// 4
// 8
```

In the vast majority of computers, little-endian is used (from a certain perspective, it can also be said that all electronic computers).

So what are big-endian and little-endian?
Simply put, it can be understood that the big-endian is from left to right (in line with the reading habits of most humans), while the little-endian is from right to left.

Here is an example:

```c
size_t n = 12345678;

/* Memory
big-endian
00 00 00 00 00 bc 61 4e

little-endian
4e 61 bc 00 00 00 00 00
*/
```

The following are two code implementation methods:

```c
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

void number_to_array()
{
    // By default, the results of this are all little-endian.

    size_t n = 12345678;
    uint8_t buf[8];

    // The first methods
    memcpy(buf, &n, sizeof(size_t));

    // The second method (Of course, this is just a demonstration,
    // in fact, the code can be simpler.)
    for(int x = 0; x < 8; ++x) {
        buf[x] = (n & (0xff << (x * 8))) >> (x * 8);
    }
}

void array_to_number()
{
    uint8_t buf[8] = {0x4e, 0x61, 0xbc, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
    size_t n = 0;

    // The first methods
    memcpy(&n, buf, sizeof(size_t));

    // The second method (Of course, this is just a demonstration,
    // in fact, the code can be simpler.)
    for(int x = 0; x < 8; ++x) {
        n = n + (buf[x] << (x * 8));
    }
}
```

You can improve the functionality you want based on the example code I provided.
If you want to implement big-endian, you only need to flip the elements in the array once (i.e. 0<->7, 1<->6, 2<->5,...).

The same applies to pointer operations, after all, in C, everything is actually a pointer.

Comment: "small end sorting" == little-endian?

Comment: @jarmod Yes, the reason for this error should be a problem with my translation software. Thank you for your reminder, and I will correct this error immediately.

Comment: "sorting" is an incorrect term as well.  The bytes aren't sorted, but in little-endian computers, the least significant byte is stored in the lowest memory address; whereas in big-endian computers the most significant byte is stored in the lowest memory address.  So 12345678 (hexadecimal bc614e) is stored little-endian as `4e 61 bc 00` , but big-endian as `00 bc 61 43`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yes, I agree with your statement. The 'sort' question should be due to my translation software, and I will modify this answer again. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: @S-N, `"%llu"` is not specified to match the type of `sizeof`.  Use `"%zu"`.

Comment: @S-N 8 is not the specified size of `size_t`.  Rather than `uint8_t buf[8];`, use `uint8_t buf[sizeof(size_t)];`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily to, but probably you don't want to do it in real life. Apart from the big endian encoding here you are just mem-copying.

Here the version in C:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 


void pack_big_endian(uint8_t *buffer, uint64_t value) {
    if (value <= 0xffffffff) {
        uint32_t big_endian_value = htonl((uint32_t)value);
        memcpy(buffer, &big_endian_value, sizeof(big_endian_value));
    } else {
        uint64_t big_endian_value = htobe64(value);
        memcpy(buffer, &big_endian_value, sizeof(big_endian_value));
    }
}

uint64_t unpack_big_endian(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size) {
    uint64_t big_endian_value;
    if (size <= sizeof(uint32_t)) {
        uint32_t network_value = 0;
        memcpy(&network_value, buffer, size);
        big_endian_value = ntohl(network_value);
    } else {
        memcpy(&big_endian_value, buffer, sizeof(big_endian_value));
        big_endian_value = be64toh(big_endian_value);
    }
    return big_endian_value;
}

int main() {
    // Test with a uint64_t value
    uint64_t value64 = 12345678901234567890ull;
    uint8_t buffer64[sizeof(value64)];
    pack_big_endian(buffer64, value64);
    printf("Encoded buffer (uint64_t): ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer64); ++i) {
        if (buffer64[i] >= 32 && buffer64[i] <= 126) {
            printf("%c", buffer64[i]);
        } else {
            printf("\\x%02x", buffer64[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    uint64_t result64 = unpack_big_endian(buffer64, sizeof(buffer64));
    printf("Decoded result (uint64_t): %lu\n", result64);

    // Test with a uint32_t value
    uint32_t value32 = 13934u;
    uint8_t buffer32[sizeof(value32)];
    pack_big_endian(buffer32, value32);
    printf("Encoded buffer (uint32_t): ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer32); ++i) {
        if (buffer32[i] >= 32 && buffer32[i] <= 126) {
            printf("%c", buffer32[i]);
        } else {
            printf("\\x%02x", buffer32[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    uint32_t result32 = (uint32_t)unpack_big_endian(buffer32, sizeof(buffer32));

    printf("Decoded result (uint32_t): %u\n", result32);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `htonl(), htobe64(), ntohl(), be64toh()` are not in the standard C library.